# What does "int k = ((int)i)" do?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm beginning coding, and i'm stuck at  `int k=((int)i)`. what does this do?

Case 1: `i = 50` is `int`.

Case 2: `i = 50.52` is `float`.

Comment: It is typecasting. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have float f = 50.2352385;

(int)f will take the integer part of the float variable , so (int)f is 50.

Comment: And in the first case, `i` is already an `int` so the casting is unnecessary.

Comment: Glad I helped. This is called typecasting. Keep in mind that you'll see this often, so it is important to understand this concept. It has more applications , not only taking the integer part of a float. Read more about it to have a better understanding